# Хотел попробовать написать массив и отсортировать его. Не получилось

Tags: java, массивы, сортировка

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = new int[10];            
    String text = "Array несортированный \n";
    for(int s:array) {
        array[s] = 2 + (int) (Math.random()*8);
        text += array[s] + " ";
    }
    boolean start = false;
    while(!start) {
        start = true;
        for(int j = 0;j < array.length-1;j++) {
            if(array[j] > array[j+1]) {
            int b = array[j+1];
            array[j+1]=array[j];
            array[j]=b;
            }

        }

    }
    text += "\nПосле сортировки\n";
    for(int s:array) {
    text += array[s];
}
System.out.println(text);
    }
```

}
Вывод:
Array несортированный 
8 9 7 8 6 2 3 5 5 5 
После сортировки
0555555555
Почему он так сортирует, в чём моя ошибка?
Заранее большое спасибо)

Comment: Ну как минимум одну ошибку видно сразу: вместо `array[j+1]=b;` надо написать `array[j]=b;`

Comment: Спасибо, поправил

Comment: Добавьте `start = false;` внутрь `if (array[j] > array[j+1]) { ... }`

Comment: К великому сожелению не помогло

Comment: Собственно сортировка `boolean start = false;
    while(!start) {
        start = true;
        for(int j = 0;j < array.length-1;j++) {
            if(array[j] > array[j+1]) {
            int b = array[j+1];
            array[j+1]=array[j];
            array[j]=b;  start = false;
            }

        }
    }` без сомнения должна работать. Проверьте внимательно свой остальной запускаемый код

Comment: Спасибо, ошибка была в заполнении (for(int s:array))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если чесно, я не очень в Java, но нашел проблему. У вас проблема в `for(int s:array)`. Я заменил на стандарнтый for и у меня заработало.
Вот: https://ideone.com/jH2RNT

На сколько я нагуглил, проблама в том, что в `for (int x : array)` x - не индекс, а значение. Поэтому и глюки.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!